# How to amplify signal for driving a more powerful motor

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, dc-motor

I have a 0-12V signal supplying max. 10A, which drives the 12V DC motor with peak consumption of 10A. I'd like to replace this motor with a more powerful 12V DC motor with the peak consumption of 30A.

The new control signal has to replicate the original one and obviously be able to drive the new motor. I have access to the external 12V, 50A power supply.

[image]
[image]

So far I came up with three possible options.

### Option 1

My first guess is to convert my signal to 0-5V PWM and use it as an input for  a driver chip such as BTN8982TA.

[image]

In that case my qeustion is how to convert my signal to PWM?

### Option 2

Another solution that I've found is to use op-amp together with MOSET tansistor. I took the circuit design from this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/228148/how-to-design-current-amplifier-circuit-to-amplify-the-signal-current-to-1a)

[image]

Does it make sense to use the amplifier here?
Won't the MOSFET overheat?

Which of the proposed solutions would be more sutiable for my task?

Comment: Did you ask a very similar question the other day?

Comment: What is the existing output circuit?  Is this being pulsed on and off with PWM?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes. I followed your advice rephrased it

Comment: There are plenty of power FETs that can use a 12V gate drive signal directly, but you'd need to look at rise and fall times of the signal you get from the existing output to see whether the FET switching times are acceptable. A suitably sized FET will not get hot from continuous current, but slow switching would greatly increase the losses.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica It looks like PWM with slew effect (as you can see in the  image with the oscilloscope). I would also consider keeping the slew rate in my new signal, although I am not sure about it's importance for driving a DC motor.

Comment: I am wondering if the slew is intentionally being added by an active circuit, or whether it's an artifact of the motor.   If the latter, then you may be able to treat it like an LED PWM amplifier, where it takes the PWM output as input to the amplifier.